# Is it illegal to carry an improvised pepper spray in the UK?

Tags: united-kingdom, england-and-wales, self-defense, weapons

Civilian possession of pepper spray is banned in the UK, due to its use in self-defence.

There are, of course, many household items that can have a similar purpose. While not nearly as effective, no attacker wants a face full of deodorant or disinfectant spray.

Is there a law against carrying items with an intent to use them in such a way?

Comment: Slight edit: Police and other law enforcement agencies are allowed to lawfully possess pepper spray (and similar items such as PAVA) if properly authorised etc.

Comment: @RockApe Fair enough. I mentally include "unless you are a police officer" to most questions like this but the clarity helps.

Comment: "Civilian possession of pepper spray is banned in the UK, due to its use in self-defence" - The logic of that line of reasoning escapes me.

Comment: @Vikki Same. But when seconds count, the police can be contacted via a web form.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Is there a law against carrying items with an intent to use them in such a way?**

[england-and-wales](/questions/tagged/england-and-wales)

**Yes**

The offence is possession of an offence weapon in a public place contrary s.1 of the [Prevention of Crime Act 1953](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/Eliz2/1-2/14?timeline=false)

> (1) Any person who without lawful authority or reasonable excuse, the proof whereof shall lie on him, has with him in any public place any offensive weapon shall be guilty of an offence, and shall be liable—
>
> (a) on summary conviction, to imprisonment for a term not exceeding six months or a fine not exceeding £200, or both;
>
> (b) on conviction on indictment, to imprisonment for a term not exceeding four years or a fine not exceeding one hundred pounds, or both.

> “offensive weapon” means any article made or adapted for use for causing injury to the person, or **intended** by the person having it with him for such use by him or by some other person.

There are similar provisions (with subtle differences) in [scotland](/questions/tagged/scotland) and [northern-ireland](/questions/tagged/northern-ireland) at s.47 of the [Criminal Law (Consolidation) (Scotland) Act 1995](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/1995/39/section/47?timeline=false) and s.93 of the [Justice Act (Northern Ireland) 2011](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/nia/2011/24/section/93?timeline=false) respectively.

Comment: Sounds like a bit of a misnomer, calling it the "prevention" of crime act when it just encourages it. +1, will almost certainly accept later.

Comment: The 1953 Act only extends to E&W so I've added its tag for precision.

Comment: Fair enough. Now I'm interested if Scots law is noteably different.

Comment: Can we just merge the two, since they're essentially the same?

Comment: You're not getting 3 upvotes. Don't be greedy.

Comment: They are three different laws, even if the wording is almost the same.

Comment: "*intended by the person*" is difficult to prove.  So does "*made or adapted for use for causing injury*" mean that if I carry a packet of Bangalore curry sauce (made for eating, and not adapted), there is no case against me?

Comment: @RayButterworth  Intent may be difficult to prove, but it is not necessarily impossible - it boils down to what the evidence can show. And don't forget it is **you** who has to prove your *lawful authority or reasonable excuse* for the possession (to the lesser standard of the balance of probabilities).

Comment: @RockApe You only have to prove lawful authority if the item in question is found to be an offensive weapon. It isnt an offensive weapon if its not adapted and the prosecution cant prove the item was carried with the intent to use as a weapon.

Comment: @Matt  Yep. I concur, but I was replying in the tone of the OP: *Is there a law against carrying items with an intent to use them in such a way?*

Comment: @RayButterworth There are ways you might inadvertently reveal your intent. If your intent is not to harm people, I wouldn't worry about it. If your intent is to harm people, I would.

Comment: @RayButterworth No, this is one of those laws that would never be used in such a circumstance.  Its purpose is largely for pile-on charges - say you got arrested in a riot where you were throwing said curry sauce jar as a projectile.  In addition to the other charges, you would also likely rack one up for the "improvised" weapon.  This gives prosecutors more charges to play poker with when striking deals - they're not meant to persecute otherwise law abiding citizens; I'm sure you'd almost always find such a charge tied in with charges for *other offences* and rarely on its own.

Comment: @RayButterworth This is useful when one guy at a riot gets a couple of months for shoving an officer and another guy at the riot lacerated someone's face with a curried molotov - the guy who added an improvised weapon to their antisocial intervention would have the additional charge for that offence and that would allow prosecutors to push for a harsher sentence than another offender who had not used such a weapon in an otherwise equally illegal act.